# CISCO-IOS-XE-TUNNEL YANG MODEL ACCESS THROUGH RESTCONF ON POSTMAN

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, cisco

Recently, I began working with RESTCONF on Postman. Today I was trying to send a HTTP request via postman to the IOS-XE-Tunnel using the path below:

https://XXX:XXX/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-tunnel:tunnel

Usually, this would return the data within the container "tunnel", however I am getting the following message:

"error-message": "uri keypath not found", "error-tag": "invalid-value", "error-type": "application"

My goal is to get the data within the leaf "**bandwidth**" from this yang module. Can anyone help me with a correct path?